# how to find column, row and data area values from cell object in Devex Pivot grid

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, pivot, devexpress-windows-ui

I am using Dev ex pivot grid to show some data on the screen. When user click on any cell in data area, I want to find out it's corresponding row, column and data area value and their field name.

I am handling `CellClick` event of devex pivot grid. 
with `PivotCellEventArgs` object I can find fieldname but not value.

I want the name and value for given cell from all perspectives (row, column and data area).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try based on the event arguments ?

Comment: I tried but couldn't find much. Can you point me to some sample code for it.

Comment: You should really ask this stuff on the DevExpress support forum. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Razor MVC you can do that

```
@Html.DevExpress().PivotGrid(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "PivotGrid";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "PivotGridPartial" };

    settings.ClientSideEvents.CellClick = @"
    function(s,e){
        var EventArgs=e; 
        console.log(EventArgs.RowValue);
        console.log(EventArgs.RowFieldName);
        console.log(EventArgs.ColumnValue);
        console.log(EventArgs.ColumnFieldName);
        console.log(EventArgs.Value); 
    }";

    settings.Fields.Add(field =>
    {
        field.Area = PivotArea.RowArea;
        ...
    });

    settings.Fields.Add(field =>
    {
        field.Area = PivotArea.ColumnArea;
        ...
    });

    settings.Fields.Add(field =>
    {
        field.Area = PivotArea.DataArea;
        ...
    });

}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```